# How to update a playlist using SoundCloud api wrapper for java

Tags: java, api, soundcloud

The soundcloud documentation has no sample for updating a playlist using java wrapper. I tried something like this but it didn't update the tracks. And no error messages returned.

```
HttpResponse resp = wrapper
  .put(Request.to("/me/playlists/123")
  .with("playlist[title]", "updated title", "playlist[tracks]", "[
    {id: 10001},
    {id: 10002}
  ]"));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a mix of Rails style form parameters and JSON.

There are two options:

1) Only use form parameters:

```
HttpResponse resp = api.put(Request.to("/playlists/123")                          
        .with("playlist[title]", "updated title")                         
        .with("playlist[tracks][][id]", 10001)     
        .with("playlist[tracks][][id]", 10002));
```

2) Submit playlist data as JSON:

```
private void updatePlaylist() {
    JSONObject json = createJSONPlaylist("updated title", 10001, 10002);
    HttpResponse resp = api.put(Request.to("/playlists/123")                     
        .withContent(json.toString(), "application/json"));
}

private JSONObject createJSONPlaylist(String title, long... trackIds) throws JSONException { 
    JSONObject playlist = new JSONObject();                                                  
    playlist.put("title", title);                                                            

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();                                                      
    json.put("playlist", playlist);                                                          

    JSONArray tracks = new JSONArray();                                                      
    playlist.put("tracks", tracks);                                                          

    for (long id : trackIds) {                                                               
        JSONObject track = new JSONObject();                                                 
        track.put("id", id);                                                                 
        tracks.put(track);                                                                   
    }                                                                                        
    return json;                                                                             
}
```

Check out the tests in the wrapper to see them in action:

- [without JSON](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper/blob/b2bead043b48f8c278cfe0f76a1e060a7e4247c4/src/test/java/com/soundcloud/api/CloudAPIIntegrationTest.java#L93)
- [with JSON](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper/blob/b2bead043b48f8c278cfe0f76a1e060a7e4247c4/src/test/java/com/soundcloud/api/CloudAPIIntegrationTest.java#L124)

Comment: I liked the second one better. Thx a lot!

Comment: yes, you should use JSON with rest APIs, not form params. the docs should be clearer on that.